# R ggridges: color geom_ridges_density_gradient based on a third variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

Does anyone know if the coloring in ggridges::geom_ridges_density_gradient can be controlled by a third variable?

To explain, if I draw a ridge diagram of wind directions in Lincoln NE (modified from an example in `help(geom_ridges_density_gradient))`, I can color according
to x (here wind direction) or y (month). For instance the following produces a nice graphic showing a prevalence of  NW winds from late fall to early spring, and SE winds during other months.

```
ggplot(lincoln_weather, aes(x = `WindDir [Degrees]`, y = `Month`, fill = stat(x))) +
     geom_density_ridges_gradient(bandwidth=22.5) + 
     scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Temp. [F]", option = "C") + xlim(0,360)
```

[image: Wind directionis in Lincoln NE]

What would be neat is to color this according to the average windspeed per (month times direction). Just adding the wind speed as a fill variable does not do the job, but returns a gray monocolor image.

```
ggplot(lincoln_weather, aes(x = `WindDir [Degrees]`, y = `Month`, fill = (`Mean Wind Speed[MPH]`))) +
 geom_density_ridges_gradient(bandwidth=22.5) + 
scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Wind direction (°)", option = "C") + xlim(0,360)
```

I cannot find examples where the colorscale is controlled by something other than `fill=stat(x)` or `fill=stat(y)`

I don't understand the `fill=stat` business well enough to advance on this. Does anyone know of examples where the coloring is done via a third variable?

Any help appreciated.